# Hyperion Foundation Services Servers are down

Tags: oracle, workspace, sharedservices

I have installed Hyperion EPM 11.1.2.4 in CentOS 7 i.e Foundation Services, Essbase and Financial Reporting. The database I have used is  SQL Server.

CentOS is not the officially supported OS for Oracle HTTP server and hence I went ahead with Weblogic HTTP server.

Once I start the weblogic server and start all the EPM services, and when I login into the weblogic server administration console, I find my foundation services server in Admin state

Also when I login into my Oracle Fusion middleware, I can see all my foundation services and financial reporting Servers down.

And hence I am unable to access the servers like workspace, calculation manager.

But few of my servers are up and are in running state such as APS,  CALC, EAS, EPMAWEBTIER. But I only can access Essbase.

I request you to check the images attached.

[Oracle Weblogic Administration Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inaoB.jpg)

[Oracle Fusion Middleware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPf6V.jpg)

1. How can I access these servers?
2. Am I having these much of troubles just because I used weblogic HTTP server instead of Oracle HTTP server?

Comment: Please attach the relevant message you have in log files. Have you checked the Certification Matrix? I have checked it [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/oracle-hyperion-epm-system-certific-131801.xls) and I do not think EPM is supported on CentOS.

Comment: @rcastellcastell Yes.. Cent OS is not officially supported OS for EPM, which means you can't get oracle http server installed but oracle gives you an option of using weblogic http server which comes with the foundation services. And that's how I got EPM Installed and configured. I am able to use Essbase.

Comment: Can you please suggest which log files do I need to check to sort this problem out. And what might be the location of these log files. Thanks

Comment: Certification does not work in that way, even Weblogic is not supported on CentOS. However, you can run it on that OS to test some stuff, but you should not use it on production. Regarding log files, I can suggest checking this [Log files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24428/logging_services.htm#WLLOG124). You can also ask your system administrator about log files.

Comment: Actually i installed EPM for learning purpose. I agree that CentOS is not the supported OS but I wonder why am I able to access and use Essbase while I just can't access the other applications. Also I tries to install oracle Linux 6 and 6.7 but those OS did not get install because of cpu compatibility issue. Oracle 8 got installed. I tried to set up EPM in oracle Linux 8 but could not find few of the required libraries in oracle's repository and hence I switched back to CentOS. Any suggestions on how can I get EPM working on oracle linux 8 would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing EPM for learning purposes, I suggest you to take the easy way and use a supported OS. Installing this software into a non supported OS will give you additional problems that you will never be sure if are caused because the non-supported OS, or because your installation / tuning is wrong.

If you download and install a Windows Server VM, it would not expire, just show you the active license message, but it will be full working.
For learning purposes / temporal Virtual machines, it is way to go.

Thanks.